# vba to click a css button with no href link

Tags: css, vba

I am trying to click a button in css with no success, the code does not give any error while running but it does not click either.

The button I want to click is here:

```
<form id="transactionHistoryReportForm" class="report-form">

  <div style="clear:both;" class="days-back-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="io-button editColumns">Edit Columns</a>
    <a class="io-button daysBackButton" data-days="1" href="#"><span>Last Day</span></a>
    <a class="io-button daysBackButton" data-days="7" href="#"><span>Last 7 Days</span></a>
    <a class="io-button daysBackButton active-days" data-days="30" href="#"><span>Last 30 Days</span></a>
    <a class="io-button daysBackButton" data-days="180" href="#"><span>Last 180 Days</span></a>
  </div>
  <!--
    <div class="currently-showing">
        <span>Currently showing:</span>
        <span data-id="currently-showing-value"></span>
    </div>
-->
  <input type="hidden" class="daysBack" name="daysBack" value="30">
  <input type="hidden" class="account" name="account" value="username">
  <input type="hidden" class="deviceId" name="deviceId" value="">
</form>
```

Last 30 days is selected by default. Last 180 days is the button to be clicked. I have tried to run the following code with no success:

```
Set oElementCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("report-form")
For Each link In oElementCollection
If link.innerHTML = "Last 180 Days" Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next link
```

However, for another link on the same website this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this simple

```
    Set backbutton = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("io-button daysBackButton").Item(Index:=3)
    backbutton.Click
```

Getting elements by class name and pointing to the third item (First is 0, therefore 4-1)